# Parse.com not sending notification after changing the package name

Tags: android, parsing, push

I am using parse.com to send my push notifications to my app. Everything was working fine until i decided to change my app package name. After i changed my android app package name, my app is unable to receive push notifications from parse.com.

I have already published my app on google playstore. Please is there a way to fix this? Thanks.

This is my manifest.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.owatech.uccsrc"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>

    <permission android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
         android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.NotificationParseRegister"
         android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme">
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.WelcomeScreen" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Welcome Home Screen Activity -->
        <activity 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity">
        </activity>

        <!-- News Feed Activity -->
        <activity 
            android:label="@string/news_feed"
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.NewsFeedActivity" 
             android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
             android:icon="@drawable/newsfeed">
               <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Notification Activity -->
        <activity
             android:label="@string/notifications" 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.Notification" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/notifications">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>


        <!-- Single Notification Activity -->
        <activity
             android:label="@string/notification"  
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.SingleNotification" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.Notification"
            android:icon="@drawable/notifications"> 
             <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.Notification" />          
        </activity>

         <!-- Constitution Activity -->
        <activity 
             android:label="@string/src_constitution" 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.Constitution" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/constitution">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>

         <!-- Constitution Details Activity -->
        <activity 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.ConstitutionDetails" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.Constitution"
            android:icon="@drawable/constitution">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.Constitution" />
        </activity>


         <!-- History Activity -->
        <activity 
             android:label="@string/history" 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.History" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/history">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- SRC COMMITTEE Activity -->
        <activity 
             android:label="@string/committees" 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.SrcCommittees" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/committee">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
                     />
        </activity>

          <!-- SRC COMMITTEE DETAILS Activity -->
        <activity 

            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.CommitteeDetails" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.SrcCommittees"
            android:icon="@drawable/committee">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.SrcCommittees" />
        </activity>

          <!-- ABOUT SRC Activity -->
        <activity 
            android:label="@string/aboutSRC" 

            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.AboutSRC" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>


          <!-- Settings Activity -->
        <activity 
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

            android:label="Settings and Preferences" 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.Settings" 
           android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
            >
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>
                  <!-- STUDENTS PORTAL Activity -->
        <activity 
            android:label="Student Portal" 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.StudentPortal" 
           android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>

            <!-- Src Executives Activity -->
        <activity 
            android:label="SRC Executives" 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.SrcExecutives" 
           android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/executives">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>

          <!-- Online Constitution Activity -->
        <activity 
            android:label="SRC Constitution" 
            android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.OnlineConstitution" 
           android:parentActivityName="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity"
            android:icon="@drawable/constitution">
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value="com.owatech.uccsrc.DashBoardActivity" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Service -->
        <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc.ParsePushReciverNotifications"
            android:exported="false">
          <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
             <action android:name="com.parse.starter.NEW_NOTIF" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />


                <category android:name="com.owatech.uccsrc" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: How are you sending the push notifications, via client -> client or parse (server) -> client? Also post the push command you are using

Comment: I am sending push notifications using parse(server) -> client

Comment: are you sending to all recipients, and are they all registered? Parse should show you if you are successfully sending them or not. If the devices are registered, it shouldnt a problem if the package name changed

Comment: Oh right I know why, link me your android manifest for registering the Parse push notifications section

Comment: Yes, I am sending to all recipients, and their devices are registered in the name of the new package name. So those with the new package name do not receive the message however, those with the old package name receives the push notification

Comment: @LucasCrawford I have added my manifest to the question

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I was not able to receive push notifications after I changed the package name even though it showed "Sent" on the parse push notification dash board. Later I realized that parse is using [FCM(Firebase Cloud Messaging)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) to implement push notifications. I have a FCM Sender Id and Server Key which I got after creating a project on firebase and adding an app to that project. While adding the app to the firebase project, I added the package name of my app. So, when I changed my package name, the connection between my app and the app on the firebase project is lost. Thats why I didn't receive notifications.

So, there are two solutions:

1. You have to create a new project on firebase and add new app to that project with the new package name. Then you will get new Sender Id and Server key which you have to replace it with older Sender Id and Server Key.
2. Add a new app with new package name to the existing firebase project.

I did the first one and it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue and discovered that I didn't update gradle file to have new package name. this fixed the issue